# How do I save a file name to a variable in cmd?

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
title Music
color 0f

:main
cls
echo Welcome to you Music!
echo.
set /p var=What would you like to do: 
if %var%==find goto find
if %var%==play goto play
goto main

:find
cls
set /p song=What song would you like me to check for (Case Sensitive): 
if exist music\"*%song%*.mp3" goto exist
if not exist music\"*%song%*.mp3" goto notExist

:exist
cls
echo %song% is here.
echo.
pause
goto main

:notExist
cls
echo %song% is not here. Check the spelling and letter case for errors.
echo.
pause
goto main

:play
cls
set /p song=Enter the name of a song to play: 
if exist music\"*%song%*.mp3" goto play2
if not exist music\"*%song%*.mp3" goto notExist
goto main

:play2
cls
set songName = [file name]

:playing
:: Will put more code later.
```

The purpose of this program is to search my music for a specific song and be able to play it from command line. I will later add code to control the music but for now I just want to be able to find the song and play it. I am using the '*' so someone could enter "Another Brick in the Wall" and let it find "Another Brick in the Wall Part 2" The issue is when saving a variable, it can not use '*' or they will be saved as part of the string.

Comment: File names cannot contain a handful of characters with quotes being one of them.  Are you planning on validating every character they enter in is a valid file name character?

Comment: I want it so I can have them write part of a name and it say that there was a result with that name. Then maybe tell the user what songs match the search.

Comment: He's saying it should work fine since you can't use `"` in a filename anyway. Are you having specific errors or problems?

Comment: @JosephLyle, I am really not understanding what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: When I run it the program will say It can not play a song because it doesn't exist. In the post I use Another Brick in the wall as an example. I want to be able to output all the songs that have what the user entered so it would say that their search of Another Brick in the Wall has 1 result: Another Brick in the Wall Part 2. If I have to I can use a text file with a list of my songs, but I want it to tell the user what songs match their search.

Comment: Keep in mind you can also use `if /i` to ignore case in checks.

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't very clear. The following should answer what I guessed from your question and comments:

```
set /p "song=What song would you like me to check for (Case insensitive): "
   REM if you are afraid of qoutes entered by the user, remove them:
   set song=%song:"=%
<nul set /p "=Songs found: "
dir /b "music\*%song%*.mp3"|find /c /v ""
echo the names are:
dir /b "music\*%song%*.mp3"
echo executing them...
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "music\*%song%*.mp3"') do (
  echo ... executing %%i
  REM whatever you use to play it
)
```